# How do I catch a Ditto?

Tags: pokemon-go

Ditto has now been released in the latest patch, and I would like to catch one.

What are the conditions to capture a Ditto? Does it show up on the nearby tracker? Or will it transform into something?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First of all, you won't just see a Ditto on your list of close Pokémon that you can catch. Ditto will first appear in your game as just a regular Pokémon. After catching the Pokémon, it might transform back into a Ditto, and it will then be added to your Pokédex. So you won't know it's a Ditto before that point. You can see an example in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWMSDLxFbjQ) here.

As for now, the current list of Pokemon which can hide a Ditto is pictured below. So just keep catching those, and you might end up with a Ditto.

[image]

Also note that if you get a Ditto after catching a specific Pokémon near you, anyone catching this exact same Pokémon will also get the Ditto.

Comment: Man, I have to catch Zubat again? *sigh* What about evolved forms of those Pokemon? Or rare Pokemon? Can they hide a Ditto as well?

Comment: It's yet to be determined if any other Pokémon than those four can hide a Ditto. I will edit the answer if any new information is up, but nearly everyone got one from one of those for now.

Comment: An anecdotal note: The difficulty of catching a Ditto seems to be separate from the Pokemon it appears as.  This morning I caught a CP 306 "Pidgey" which turned out to be a Ditto.  The circle was green, whereas a Pidgey of that CP would have likely been yellow or orange.

Comment: @SpectralFlame Future readers shouldn't expect that though. This may be a bug

Comment: @acbabis, SpectralFlame's anecdote seems reasonable to me.  Why do you think it is a bug?  A Ditto's appearance is camouflaged, but its stats and capture rate are not.

Comment: Any idea on the percent chance that a given common Pokemon will be a ditto?

Comment: No idea for that yet. If ever I get this information, I will also edit the answer.

Comment: @Batophobia I would _guess_ that that's completely random - it's just a different spawn. eg. a Ditto spawning rather than a Pidgey, and the Ditto just happens to be hidden.

Comment: Imagine catching a Dragonite and it transforms into a Ditto

Comment: I caught two Ditto today. Both Zubat.

Comment: Just an aside, I've unfortunately caught Ditto disguised as an Alakazam and a Koffing, so it looks like it's not limited to the low-tier Pokémon in terms of what it can disguise itself as.

Comment: @Vemonus Oh, that's the first report I get from those two. But you are usually a reliable source, so I guess that's true. I hardly got more information on any real proof of other Pokémon transforming since the hype of the first days, so I can't confirm if it is really working for _any_ Pokémon. I will edit the answer to include that fact at least.

Comment: I've just had a Hoohoot turn into a Ditto so it looks like the Gen2 commons are also a possibility.