# Is it possible to find Dittos by catching some rare Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sometimes I am thinking if I encounter a Dragonite or Lapras, will it turn into a Ditto?

It is requiring the possibility to catch dittos from rare Pokémon.

Hope no Dittos from those rare Pokémon.

Comment: I think http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292075/how-do-i-catch-a-ditto kinda covers it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, only common Pokémon like Zubat and Magicarp have been shown to potentially be a Ditto in disguise. So it is most likely not possible unless proven otherwise.

Comment: I found [a site](https://pkmngowiki.com/wiki/Ditto_(Pokémon)) stating Ditto can be disguised as pokemon that are categorized under 2km or 5km eggs.  I believe the rare pokemon you speak of are 10km eggs.