# Is there any way to tell where I can find a Ditto?

Tags: pokemon-go

Since Ditto was released, it's been a struggle to find one, purely because they are always disguised as another Pokemon. However, often other players share information on where they caught one.

For example, someone might post that they caught a Ditto down at the beach, disguised as a Magikarp.

Is it possible to find a Ditto in such a way? If I were to go to the same location, could I find one too, or is it still completely random?

Comment: @Vemonus Yes, I noticed that after the fact. I retracted my flag

Comment: I've found 2 Ditto's so far, and both were in different places. I've been back to the first place multiple times, to no avail. It seems to be a random chance when a pokemon is spawned that it will be a ditto, and everyone who can see that pokemon in the world will see it transform upon catching it. So if you're with friends and one of them catches one, you should be able to as well (good if you're low on pokeballs and don't want more darned pidgeys or ratatta).

- It is worth noting both of my Ditto came from what appeared to be Ratatta.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I catch a Ditto?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292075/how-do-i-catch-a-ditto)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is an exact duplicate, but it does seem to answer the question above on _is it possible to find a Ditto in such a way?_  The answer to this question from the other post is the last sentence in the accepted answer: _Also note that if you get a Ditto after catching a specific Pokémon near you, anyone catching this exact same Pokémon will also get the Ditto._

Comment: @TimmyJim that may be true, but during the [trial period for duping](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/duplicate-questions-a-trial), we should only close questions as dupes based on the questions themselves, not answers that may cover the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like all Pokemon, Ditto spawn randomly. Their spawns seem relatively low (compared to the Pidgey and Rattata they like to pretend to be). Personally, I've only caught 4 since they were made available. It might be worth noting that they were all caught in the same place and that I haven't caught any elsewhere, though I haven't really gone on Pokemon-catching walks since long before Ditto were out.

That said, it's not yet confirmed whether or not Ditto can have nests. [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5ee0r4/found_ditto/dacg18z/) says yes, but there is not enough evidence to determine this conclusively.

> Can confirm Ditto spawn points. Caught two 2 hours apart, first being a Pidgey, second a Rattata, from the exact same location.

Basically, since Ditto are so new and aren't readily visible/observable, there is much that is not yet known about them. That said, your best bet to finding a Ditto is to catch everything you see.

Another helpful tip is that if a Pokemon is *exceptionally* and *uncharacteristically* difficult to catch, it's somewhat likely to be a Ditto. For instance, the past two Ditto I've caught, I figured were Ditto prior to being revealed. The first was a mid-range CP Rattata that escaped two razzed Excellent Great balls and the other was a mid-range CP Pidgey that escaped three Excellent Pokeballs.

Comment: For what its worth, I just caught my second Ditto in the same location as I caught my first one in.

Comment: @imaichiko I've caught 7, and they've been all over the place in no discernible pattern. Only two were in the same place (which is highly likely to be mere coincidence because it's a spawn spot beside my house).